# Is there a short way to count dictionaries values in pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, counter

I'm trying to count the number of times that the values in a dictionary appear in a column of dataframe that contains a stemmed text.

I made a list with the values and then applied in the counter function to count every single value in each row

```
dictionary = {'c-1' : ['x', 'y', 'z'], 'c-2' : ['a', 'b']}

words_list = list()
for key in dictionary.keys():
    words_list.append(dictionary[key])
test = [val for sublist in words_list for val in sublist]

from collections import Counter
text['Counter'] = text['Text'].apply(lambda x: Counter([word for word in x if word in test]))
```

text = {'text': ['some text', some text'], 'Counter': [Counter({a = 1, x = 2}), Counter({b = 2, y = 4, z = 3})]}

I'd like to show a column with the result for each row. Maybe I chose a large way to do that. I think that is a direct way to working directly in the dictionary, but I don't know exactly how.

Comment: Please provide the sample data and your expected output.

Comment: For each dictionary key, you could do something like `text['Text'].str.count(r'x|y|z')`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, use `collections.Counter` with `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

d = {'c-1' : ['x', 'y', 'z'], 'c-2' : ['a', 'b']}
s = pd.Series(['abc', 'xyz', 'abda'])
new_s = s.str.findall('|'.join(chain(*d.values()))).apply(Counter)
print(new_s)
```

Output:

```
0            {'b': 1, 'a': 1}
1    {'z': 1, 'x': 1, 'y': 1}
2            {'b': 1, 'a': 2}
dtype: object
```

Comment: What does it mean the '|'?

Comment: It is an `or` expression in regex. Finds any character that is in the dictionary values.

Comment: Alright.But when I run the line, Python's return me: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: It seems like `text['Text']` contains `float`. In such a case, the list comprehension (the way you did it) would be the best shot.

Comment: Why text['Text'] could cointains float if it is only text?